# Custom printing from Firefox (Windows Only)

Tags: firefox, printing, xpcom

I have created a .NET Windows Forms component that runs within IE via an `<object />` tag and allows me to print to a thermal label printer directly from a web page using the Windows API's to bypass the driver and send raw commands.

This all works, but my customer is now asking for similar functionality from Firefox!

What I need to do is to be able to pass the name of the printer that I want to use (this is configured within the web application) and then pass a string that is to be sent directly to the printer without being intercepted by the driver translation. I can acheive all of this by gaining access to the following Win32 API's (as I currently do from my .NET component)...

- OpenPrinter
- StartDocPrinter
- StartPagePrinter
- WritePrinter
- EndPagePrinter
- EndDocPrinter
- ClosePrinter

I have looked at the options, and as far as I can see the only path available is XPCOM. Can anybody advise me as to whether I have reached the right conclusion before I start down this path as it appears that there is a great deal of work involved in creating an XPCOM extension and I would hate to spend a lot of time on it only to find out that either ...

- There is an easier way
- XPCOM will not do what I want!

Thanks in advance.

BTW: I am not looking to enable the existing .NET component to work in Firefox, I believe that I will have to start from scratch and create a Firefox extension that can be used instead.

Comment: Did you find answer to this question?